# Finding unique values in pandas column where each row has multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following column in a `dataframe` which contains colors seprated by `|`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['RED|BROWN|YELLOW', 'WHITE|BLACK|YELLOW|GREEN', 'BLUE|RED|PINK']})
```

I want to find all unique colors from the column.

**Expected Output**:

```
{'YELLOW', 'BLACK', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'BROWN', 'GREEN', 'WHITE', 'PINK'}
```

I don't mind if it is `list` or `set`.

**What I tried**:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|"))

colors = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    colors.extend(row['x'])

print(set(colors))
```

Which is working fine but I am looking for more efficient solution as I have large dataset.

Comment: is order important?

Comment: @anky_91 Nope that's why I'm ok with either `list` or `set`

Comment: okay, then you can check with itertools, posted something with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) (which is arguably the fastest in flattening lists ) with set;

```
import itertools
set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.x.str.split('|')))
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'BLACK', 'BLUE', 'BROWN', 'GREEN', 'PINK', 'RED', 'WHITE', 'YELLOW'}
```

Another possible solution with `functools` which is almost as fast as itertools:

```
import functools
import operator
set(functools.reduce(operator.iadd, df.x.str.split('|'), []))
```

**Note** you can also use `sum()` which seems readable but not quite as fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
set(df.loc[:, 'x'].str.split('|', expand=True).values.ravel())
```

or

```
set(df.loc[:, 'x'].str.split('|', expand=True).values.ravel()) - set([None])
```

Comment: Why it returns `None`? can you please explain?

Comment: Since items in column `x` expanded in arrays (different number of colors per item) of different length some items of  the data frame `df.loc[:, 'x'].str.split('|', expand=True)` becomes `None`; you need to exclude None from the result

Answer (score 1):

```
list(df.x.str.split('|', expand=True).stack().reset_index(name='x').drop_duplicates('x')['x'])
```

**Output**

```
['RED', 'BROWN', 'YELLOW', 'WHITE', 'BLACK', 'GREEN', 'BLUE', 'PINK']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `set(df['x'].str.split('|').values.sum())`

This will also remove `None` form the output

`{'YELLOW', 'RED', 'WHITE', 'BROWN', 'GREEN', 'PINK', 'BLUE', 'BLACK'}`